# Check if any sprites in a list have gone past a certain x coordinate?

Tags: python, python-2.7, class, pygame

I have a class called allies and all of the allies join the the group AlliedList. How do you check that whole group to see if x < 200. So that then you can change a variable.

Comment: Where is the code?

Comment: posting some code snippets would make your question more understandable. Showing what you already tried will probably spare you some downvotes.

Answer (score 0):

Posting the code would be really useful here but based on the information provided I can give the following answer.

Give the property xPosition to your Allies class. This would be updated every frame then you can simply check through the AlliedList with Allies.xPosition to return their x coordinate.

I hope this helps, again if you post code we can help further!

Answer (score 0):

As the others said, if you would add your code it will be easier to help, but that's maybe what you meant:

```
flag = True
for al in AlliedList:
    if al.get_x_position>200:
        flag = False
```

If you did'nt mean to this kind of solution please describe your problem with more data.